Last look window in us treasuries
Last look window is always discussed for Fx but I was wondering if people analyzed also its effect in other Asset Classes like US treasuries?
Because I think that the holding time of a quote in US treasuries through TradeWeb for example is $1s$ which is a lot. So, I was wondering how it impacts Market Makers, and if there have been any proposals to adjust the last look window?

As you mentioned "last look" is a concept relating to foreign exchange, I have not heard the term used in connection with US Tsys.

@nbbo2 yes I know, but I don't understand why because on Rfqs there's a holding time of 1s
